# How to convert my text files (each containing a username+password pair) into CSV in order to import them to KeePass via bash(cygwin)

Tags: bash, csv, cygwin

I'd like to use [Keepass](http://keepass.info/) (win10x64).

The problem is that, I have my passwords gathered all these years like this:
each username/password pair in a separate text file,
having as filename the domain name of the relevant password,
and inside each .txt file, the first line is the username, and the 2nd the password (both without a prefix).

For example:

Filename: `reddit.com`  (it also has the .txt extension but that can be omitted)
Contents:

```
my_username  
my_Password
```

In order the above to become an CSV it must be converted into:

```
"Account","Login Name","Password","Web Site", "Notes"
"Entry 1","my_username","my_password","http://reddit.com", ""
```

i.e.

```
"Account","Login Name",  "Password",    "Web Site",          "Notes"
"Entry 1","my_username", "my_password", "http://reddit.com", ""
```

*Note: if there is a comma (`,`), double quote(`"`) or backslash(`\`) in the password then it must be escaped with a backslash.*

**How can this be done via a bash script (cygwin)?**

---

The code snippets I have gathered so far:

1. **How can I prepend a string to the beginning of each line in a file?**           ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586349/how-can-i-prepend-a-string-to-the-beginning-of-each-line-in-a-file))

   ```
   awk '{print "prefix" $0}' file
   ```
2. **Print nth Line From file.txt**                                                     ([source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-scripting-using-awk/))

   ```
   awk "NR==2{print;exit}" file.txt                // for printing the 2nd line
   ```
3. **execute a command to all found files recursively**

   ```
   find . -name "*.txt" -execdir *command*
   ```

   or alternatively

   ```
   for file in /cygdrive/c/folder/*; do 
        *command*                    // command example:   mv "$file" "${file}/.."   
   done
   ```

---

So, my script should start with:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -execdir        awk '{print '"Account","Account","Login Name","Password","Web Site", "Notes"' $0}' "$file"
```

I'm stuck at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input files:

1. yahoo.net.txt
2. gougle.com.txt
3. reddit.com.txt

Contents of `yahoo.net.txt`:

```
user1-yaho0
pas,,
```

Contents of `gougle.com.txt`:

```
user1-google
pas"wor,d
```

Contents of `reddit.com.txt`:

```
user1-reddit
pas\wor\d
```

With this input, the following quick and dirty script does the job:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "\"Account\",\"Login Name\",\"Password\",\"Web Site\",\"Notes\"" > output.csv
num=0
for f in `find . -type f -name '*.txt'` ; do

num=$((num + 1))
user=`head -1 "$f"`
password=`sed 1d "$f" | sed -r 's/([\\,"])/\\\\\1/g'`
domain=`basename "$f" | sed 's/\.txt$//'`

echo "\"$num\",\"$user\",\"$password\",\"$domain\",\"\"" >> output.csv

done
```

Contents of `output.csv`:

```
"Account","Login Name","Password","Web Site","Notes"
"1","user1-reddit","pas\\wor\\d","reddit.com",""
"2","user1-yaho","pas\,\,","yahoo.net",""
"3","user1-google","pas\"wor\,d","gougle.com",""
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`

```
 awk 'BEGIN{print "\"Account\",\"Login Name\",\"Password\",\"Web Site\",\"Notes\""}
{ if (FNR==1){
         user=$0;a+=1};
  if(FNR==2){
         print "\""a"\",\""user"\",\""$0"\",\""gensub(/\.txt/,"","",FILENAME)"\","}}' *.txt
```

Use awk special variable `FNR` to get the 1st and 2nd line from each `*.txt` file and string manipulation function `gensub` to remove `.txt` from `FILENAME`( an `awk` special variable) for URL column.